# An issue with Parse.com ListView tutorial

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform, textview

I'm having a problem with [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial/#comment-2091806668) tutorial.
I have only one TextView every row.
When I'm trying to populate the ListView, it looks like this:

A

A

A

instead of:

A

B

C

I mean, it shows the first row TextView text for all of the TextViews, instead of different TextViews.

This is the doInBackground method of the AsyncTask, as it shown at the tutorial:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array
        worldpopulationlist = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();
        try {
            // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Restaurants");
            query.whereWithinKilometers("Location", SearchActivity.loc, 2.0);
            query.setLimit(5);
            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject country : ob) {
                WorldPopulation map = new WorldPopulation();
                map.setName((String) country.get("Name"));
                worldpopulationlist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Post your own code here. Then we can help.

Comment: @Asim it's the same code as it on the website. I didn't change nothing, except that it has only one TextView every row, instead of 4 TextViews every row.

Comment: Having one textview and 4 textviews calls for very different approaches, if I'm not wrong. If you simply want to show one textview per row, you don't need a custom adapter. A simple ArrayAdapter will work.

Comment: I've tried it and I think that ArrayAdapter doesn't work with whereWithinKilometers

Comment: are you providing data through array while calling adapter in your activity ....this sort of problem can be arised when you are not providing data to the adapter.....share what you are writing to set adapter in your current layout class

Comment: I've added the code to the question.

Comment: I've just tried it with 2 TextViews instead of one and it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem. I've accidently changed private to public static on WorldPopulation class. The answer is to change it back to privatefor all of the variables, so instead of this:

```
public static String Name;
```

It will be this:

```
private String Name;
```